# CSS Grid Layout - grid-row-gap every 2 Rows

Tags: html, css, css-grid, grid-layout

Is it possible to have a grid layout with row gaps, but the gap is only every 2 rows?
Or have a border every 2 rows?

After that I would like to span elements over the grid. Place an extra element as line will destroy the grid, I can't overlap an already filled area.

Example Code:

```css
body{
  background-color:gray;
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(12,20px);
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color:lightgray;
}

.grid > div {
  background: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid cadetblue;
}



#element{
  grid-row: 5 / span 3;
}
```

```html
The lightgrey element should have lines/borders every second grid row
<div class="grid">
  <div id="element">Element</div>
</div>
```

**Example Layout:**

[image: Example Layout]

**Span Element over it:**

[image: Span Element over it]

Other solutions are also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

To span the elements over you can use `grid-row-start` and `grid-row-end` property like -

```css
    .item1 {
      grid-row-start: 3;
      grid-row-end: 6;
      background-color:red;
    }
    
    .grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(12,20px);
  border: 1px solid black;

}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
      <div class="item1">1</div>
      <div class="item2">2</div>
      <div class="item3">3</div>  
      <div class="item4">4</div>
      <div class="item5">5</div>
      <div class="item6">6</div>
      <div class="item7">7</div>
      <div class="item8">8</div>  
    </div>
```

For the row gap don't use `grid-row-gap` and just add margins like

```
.grid > div:nth-child(4n + 1), .grid > div:nth-child(4n + 2) {
    margin-top: 1em;
}

.grid > div:nth-child(4n + 3), .grid > div:nth-child(4n + 4) {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

instead of adding negative margins. It will work the same. (personally i don't prefer adding negative margins as it complicates the layout, but its your choice)

Comment: Yep... and now combine @kukkuz answer with yours ;)

Comment: yep, you can do that. But I am trying to look for a better way for row-gap than to add negative margins. Will post if will find something :-)

Answer (score 0):

To have a *row gap* every two rows, you can try setting `grid-row-gap` property for the *grid container* and then use *negative margins* and some *nth-child logic* to adjust the row gaps (assuming this is a 2-column layout).

This's a hack at best, anyway see the demo below:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 1em;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  counter-reset: counter;
}

.grid > div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid cadetblue;
}

.grid > div:before {
  counter-increment: counter;
  content: counter(counter);
}

.grid > div:nth-child(4n + 1), .grid > div:nth-child(4n + 2) {
  margin-bottom: -0.5em;
}

.grid > div:nth-child(4n + 3), .grid > div:nth-child(4n + 4) {
  margin-top: -0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a solution for the first part of my question, but no solution for my second problem. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WqKxZR

Comment: @JanneckLange this solution do not solve the second one as *spanning rows* breaks the nth-child-negative-margin logic

Answer (score 0):

Yes but by defining a `grid-auto-rows` structure to match the required extra "gap".

It's unsemantic since we are using elements *just for styling* and spacing.

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-auto-rows: 20px 20px 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.grid>div {
  border: 1px solid cadetblue;
  background: lightblue;
}

.item.red {
  background: red;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.item.spanner {
  grid-row: span 3;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item red"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item red"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item spanner"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution. place hr elements with position absolute and make them large to flow over everthing. z-index will place the line under my element.

```css
body{
  background-color:gray;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.1fr 1fr 0.1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(18, 15px);
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color:lightgray;
}

#element{
  grid-column:2;
  grid-row: 3 / span 6;
  background-color:green;
  z-index:3;
  margin: 5px;
}

.H1{
  grid-column:1;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.H2{
  grid-column:1;
  grid-row: 7;
}

.H3{
  grid-column:1;
  grid-row: 13;
}

.Hr{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  height: 2px;
  width:100%;
}

.Vr{
    position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  width: 2px;
  height:100%;
}

.V1{
    grid-column:1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.V1{
    grid-column:3;
  grid-row: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="H1"><hr class="Hr" /></div>
  <div class="H2"><hr class="Hr"/></div>
  <div class="H3"><hr class="Hr"/></div>
  <div class="V1"><hr class="Vr" /></div>
  <div class="V2"><hr class="Vr" /></div>
  <div id="element">Element</div>
</div>
```

Comment: so it's only about visual result? if so I have an easier solution without extra element

Answer (score -2):

```html
 

<head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="row mb-5 table-bordered">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">1</div>
        <div class="col-6">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">3</div>
        <div class="col-6">4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row table-bordered">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">A</div>
        <div class="col-6">B</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">C</div>
        <div class="col-6">D</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is a bootstrap grid layout. I work with the CSS Grid layout: https://blog.kulturbanause.de/2013/12/css-grid-layout-module/